# Is it possible to find Dusk Lycanroc in the wild?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

I'm exploring *Dalipaza Passage*, and I noticed that Midday and Midnight Lycanroc forms wander around during day and night. I tried to walk there during dusk, but no Lycanroc spawned during that daytime.

Am I unlucky or can't Dusk Lycanroc be found in the wild?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to find a Dusk form Lycanroc in the wild. The [Day/Night](https://www.serebii.net/scarletviolet/daynightcycle.shtml) cycle is roughly 72 minutes, with Dusk only being 3 minutes long, so finding Dusk form Lycanroc can be tricky. Based on [this guide](https://game8.co/games/Pokemon-Scarlet-Violet/archives/398561#hl_4), they can be found in mountains of the North Province (though it didn't say they can't be caught in the Dalipaza Passage).

There is a video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2D1H0g4AmA&ab_channel=RandomRam) showing this can be done.

[image: Wild Dusk Lycanron]

Comment: After 10 days I managed to find one in North Location 1, but that damn Pokemon knows Roar T.T